# How i can install crystal report silent mode using InstallShield?

Tags: command-line, crystal-reports, installshield, crystal-reports-2010

I create a Setup with Installshield 2010. my setup has a prerequisites for reporting viewer so i want to install CR_Runtime13.0.12.msi silently. for this situation we want a command to start the cr_runtime setup silent, after many searches on the net i found this command.

```
msiexec /i "ISSetupPrerequisites\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12.msi" /qb /norestart
```

when i use this command on Cmd it works well and setup is begins silently with progress bar but when i use this command on installshield, it show me an error and a help every time.

please help me to create a command for installshield to install cr_runtime13.0.12 silently.

at the end i Attached installshield command page and my help to this Question.

There are solutions in the StackOverFlow it does not Clear.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the msi to the Files To Include. Installshield does the rest.

Try to change the command line only to

/qb /norestart

PS:
I think the command is "/qn /norestart" and not qb.

Remove everything else.

Try it